# Search form with pagination

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with the pagination of the records result.

I would like to show all the users saved in a db table using a search form and paginate them accordingly to following script:

```
http://papermashup.com/easy-php-pagination/
```

If I insert manually the gendre value in the query below,

```
"SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE playerSex  = '0' LIMIT $start, $limit";
```

I have no problem to display all the female users,

If I send the value through the form like this

```
"SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE playerSex  ='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['gendre']) ."' 
LIMIT $start, $limit";
```

Only the first page displays the female users. Clicking on page 2 the script shows all the records (male and female) and not the requested female ones.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: You need to save or transfer your query over to the next page. Your next page doesn't know what the search query is.

Comment: It's because your pagination links doesn't works fine. you should append `&gender=...` in your pagination href.

Comment: Hi putvande, how can I save or transfer the query over the next page?

Answer (score 0):

You should keep your `gender` option in your pagination href. something like this:

```
<?php
    foreach $key.... //pagination creator loop
    if(isset($_GET['gender']))
        $href = $key . '&gender=' . $_GET['gender'];
    else
        $href = $key;
?>
```

Comment: I think you meant `$href` instead of `$herf` ;-)

Comment: Although OP's "gender" is (mis)spelled as "gendre" (actually that's the French spelling for gender), is using `$_GET['gendre']` so it's unclear if OP did in fact misspell it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry I got wrong. but the code works fine

Comment: You changed the first one, but the other one still shows as `$_GET['gender']` and `&gender` - all must read as `gendre`

Answer (score 0):

Append the GET parameter in pagination url.
e.g. you have page url "http://papermashup.com/easy-php-pagination/" and 
pagination url

```
"http://papermashup.com/easy-php-pagination/?page=1" , 
"http://papermashup.com/easy-php-pagination/?page=2" , 
"http://papermashup.com/easy-php-pagination/?page=3".......
```

In pagination Url add the GET parameter like

```
if($_GET['playerSex'] !="")
{

    $playerSex = "&playerSex=".$_GET['playerSex'];

}

"http://papermashup.com/easy-php-pagination/?page=1$playerSex"
"http://papermashup.com/easy-php-pagination/?page=2$playerSex"
"http://papermashup.com/easy-php-pagination/?page=3$playerSex" .......
```